# ReactJS: How can I let a Parent prop be used globally in the child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent class Tab.js which I have a few components

`<ProductSquare id = {"Bumper123"}/>`

How can I use `this.props.id` not only in the `return` section of my component but also so a method in the child component can access the id.

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you mean "the return section" of your component, like what you return in render? Also, every method in a component has access to `this.props`. If you pass `id` as a prop to a child component, then every method in that child can use `this.props.id` to reference it.

Comment: this.props is available to any method in your child component (ProductSquare) - you can use it in render (hence in the render's "return" section) or use it anywhere else you like. Can you post some code to show that isn't working for you?

Comment: Thank you @Jayce444 and Chris. I did find out that you can use props globally. I just did not realize that. Thanks.